# Matplotlib's stackplot change colors for overlapping regions

Tags: matplotlib, stacked-chart, stacked-area-chart, area-chart

When I draw a stacked area plot using Matplotlib's `stackplot`, if a set of `y` values has a negative number in it, then that area will overlap with the area underneath. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.stackplot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,0,-1])
plt.show()
```

[image: stackplot]

You can see the top set of `y` values are in orange. Since the right most `y` value is `-1`, it overlaps with the blue region. This is fine for my purposes. Except, I need that to be clear it's an overlap as opposed to the blue region just stayed at `y=2.0` from `x=2.0` to `x=3.0` and the orange area is positive. Can overlaps like this be set to a different color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can overlaps like this be set to a different color?

Yes, you could draw the second y data in two runs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y1 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [1,0,-1]
polys = plt.stackplot([1,2,3], y1, np.maximum(y2, 0), np.minimum(y2, 0))
```

[image]

I think, however, a better solution would be to make the colors semi-transpartent, maybe with additional hatching:

```
polys = plt.stackplot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,0,-1], alpha=0.3)
for poly, hatch in zip(polys, ['|', '-']):
    poly.set_hatch(hatch)
    poly.set_edgecolor(poly.get_facecolor())
```

[image]

Comment: Love the hatching!